# Faster definition of "matrix multiplication" in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication, convolution

I need to define matrix multiplication from scratch, as instead of multiplying each constant together, each constant is actually another array and any two arrays need to be "convolved" together (I don't think it's necessary to define what a convolution is here).

I have made a picture that hopefully explains what I'm trying to say better:

[image: here]

The code I have to do this with is this:

```
for row in range(arr1.shape[2]):
    for column in range(arr2.shape[3]):
        for index in range(arr2.shape[2]): # Could also be "arr1.shape[3]"
            out[:, :, row, column] += convolve(
                arr2[:, :, :  , column][:, :, index],
                arr1[:, :, row, :     ][:, :, index]
            )
```

However, this method had proved to be very slow for me, so I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

Comment: How is `convolve` defined or imported?

Comment: If your concern is performance, then what about [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)? I guess that's definitely faster than 3 nested python loops. Are you tasked to write it from scratch exactly this way?

Comment: How would I use numpy.dot though? I cant use multiplication as that function does,  everywhere you would multiply 2 numbers together in normal "matrix multiplication" it needs to use `convolve()` instead.

Comment: pls provide a sample input code to try on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intermediate fits in memory the following should be reasonably efficient

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve,convolve

# example
rng = np.random.default_rng()
A = rng.random((5,6,2,3))                    
B = rng.random((4,3,3,4))                    

# custom matmul

Ae,Be = A[...,None],B[:,:,None]
shsh = np.maximum(Ae.shape[2:],Be.shape[2:])
Ae = np.broadcast_to(Ae,(*Ae.shape[:2],*shsh))
Be = np.broadcast_to(Be,(*Be.shape[:2],*shsh))
C = fftconvolve(Ae,Be,axes=(0,1),mode='valid').sum(3)         

# original loop for reference

out = np.zeros_like(C)
for row in range(A.shape[2]):
    for column in range(B.shape[3]):
        for index in range(B.shape[2]): # Could also be "A.shape[3]"
            out[:, :, row, column] += convolve(
                B[:, :, :  , column][:, :, index],
                A[:, :, row, :     ][:, :, index],
                mode='valid'
            )

print(np.allclose(C,out))

# True
```

By doing the convolution in bulk we reduce the total number of fft's we have to do.

If need be this could be further optimized for both speed and memory by doing the sum reduction in Fourier space using `einsum`. This would require doing the fft convolution by hand, though.

Comment: Thanks! But can you make it work for `fftconvolve(mode='valid')`?

Comment: `C = fftconvolve(*np.broadcast_arrays(A[...,None],B[:,:,None]),axes=(0,1),mode='valid').sum(3)`

Comment: This works, however, the first 2 dimensions (the ones we perform the convolution on) of the arrays have to be the same shape (I need them to be different), or else I get the error `shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`.

Comment: `Ae,Be = A[...,None],B[:,:,None]` `shsh = np.maximum(Ae.shape[2:],Be.shape[2:])` `Ae = np.broadcast_to(Ae,(*Ae.shape[:2],*shsh)` `Be = np.broadcast_to(Be,(*Be.shape[:2],*shsh)`

Comment: Well, I don't want it to turn both arrays into the same size... I would like to do the normal `mode='valid'` convolution (the matrices I'm convoluting are `A[:, :, m, n]` and `B[:, :, k, w]`) where a matrix-multiplication of the last 2 dimensions in `A` and `B` would multiply 2 numbers together. Like my original question shows (hopefully).

Comment: It doesn`t. Just try it.

Comment: Really? When I tried it it produced an error here: `Ae = np.broadcast_to(Ae,(*Ae.shape[:2],*shsh)` Because of a bracket imbalance, so I closed it off; `Ae = np.broadcast_to(Ae,(*Ae.shape[:2],*shsh))`, and it made `Be`'s dimensions (of the first 2) like `Ae`'s.

Comment: Ok, I realized you can make a `mode='full'` convolution (which your original answer used) into a `mode='valid'` convolution by simply taking off the extra values `mode='full'` computes, I've done this (it works) and tested how long it takes compared to my previous method, the answer is that it's faster by about 100 times. Im happy with this, but if you really want you can still come up with an answer, I'll happily take one, but you don't have to. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer, as I said it just works for me. I'm surprised the speedup you're seeing is that large.